# How to implement this kind of inheritance

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection

Say I have some definitions as following:

```
public interface ISerializable<TSource, TDest>
{
  TDest Serialize();
  TSource Deserialize(TDest dto);
}
```

Now I want all my objects to implement ISerializable. So:

```
public interface IA<TSource, TDest> : ISerializable<TSource, TDest> {...}
public interface IB<TSource, TDest> : ISerializable<TSource, TDest> {...}
// more interface declaration...

public class A : IA
{
    // implementation here
}
// more class declaration...
```

The point is, I'm doing dependency injection. I want people to use IA for everything, I don't want them to know the existence of class A. Now I wanted to provide a common implementation for Serialize/Deserialize because most of them are the same.

```
public abstract class Serializable<TSource, TDest> : ISerializable<TSource, TDest>
{
  TDest Serialize() {...}
  TSource Deserialize(TDest dto) {...}
}
```

The problem is, interface exposed to user is IA/IB/... while common implementation of Serialize/Deserialze is in abstract class C. I can implement IA and derive from C at the same time, but final user still can't use the serialization functions because they are declared in C.
Is there any way to do this?

EDIT:
If I change IA to AbstractA, then AbstractA can derive from Serializable, sort of solved the problem. But I can't use some features of interface such as, I can declare properties like

```
public interface IA
{
  string Name { get; }
}
public class A : IA
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This way I can hide the setter from final user, while when assembling these classes I can still access the setter without restriction because I'm using A other than IA internally.

Comment: Can you implement you interface in a class? let's call it `BaseClass` and then on the classes that you want to use the serialization you just inherit from `BaseClass` and call it's methods ?

Comment: @juanreyesv Hi, thanks for the answer. I edited my question for further explanation.

Comment: just change your interface to whatever you need it to be at that level.  You can inherit from more than one interface.

Comment: @DeveloperGuo Sorry I don't fully understand your answer. By more than one interface you mean class A derive from both ISerializable and IA?

Comment: if you need an interface that exposes both get;set; and one with just get, you can have an interface for each.  Your abstract class can implement both.

Comment: You might find it easier to use composition rather than inheritance to solve this problem.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: @DeveloperGuo You mean have IA1 and IA2 to define getter and setter separately?

Comment: IA1 { prop1 {get;}} IA2 { prop1{get;set;}}  A : IA1, IA2

Comment: @DeveloperGuo I think this way I still have to implement both IA1 IA2 in my AbstractA, maybe an abstract property though. Are you suggesting  I should expose IA1 to final user? then they still can't access ISerializable methods.

Comment: It's up to you what you want to do.  I was addressing the problem you put up saying "you can't use some features of interface".  If you want classes to share a serializable implementation, you will need to use composition (@Ian) or a shared base class (@juanreyesv).

Comment: @DeveloperGuo I actually just want it to be simple and understandable. If I just want to solve it, I can use ((ISerializable) IA).Serialize. But there's definitely no guarantee that IA can be converted to ISerializable, this makes people reading my code confused. So which is a better way that resolve my problem and makes more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still unclear about what is confusing for you.  If a class needs a version of IA that has ISerialize methods, use IASerializeAware which implements both IA and ISerializeable.  Does that help?

```
public interface ISerializable<out T1, T2>
{
    T2 Serialize();
    T1 Deserialize(T2 dto);
}

public interface IA<out T1, T2>
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public interface IASerializeAware<out T1,T2> :  IA<T1, T2>, ISerializable<T1,T2>
{
}

public abstract class ASerializeAwareBase<T1, T2> : Serializable<T1,T2>, IASerializeAware<T1,T2>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Serializable<T1, T2> : ISerializable<T1, T2>
{
    public T2 Serialize()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public T1 Deserialize(T2 dto)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I may have made some mistake here. What confused me is that I thought both IASerializeAware and Serializable are derived from ISerializable, then in ASerializeAwareBase I'll have to implement both IASerializeAware.Serialize/Deserialize and Serializable.Serialize/Deserialize. That's what we need to do when 2 interfaces have methods with same signature. But it turns out I'm wrong. I'll try it out and see if I have any further question. Thanks